# select drop duplicates from table based in the date

Tags: sql

I want drop duplicates in select from table below based in the date column taking only the last date

Table

| Col1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| bar | 2019-12-24 |
| foo | 2019-12-25 |
| foo | 2019-12-27 |
| bar | 2019-12-01 |
| bar | 2019-12-31 |

expected result of select

| Col1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 2019-12-27 |
| bar | 2019-12-31 |

Comment: `SELECT col1, max(Date) as Date FROM yourtable GROUP BY col1`?

Comment: Next time please tag your request with your DBMS. In this case the solution is so basic that it should work in all RDBMS, but often this is not the case and in order to post appropriate answers we must know your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1, MAX(Date) FROM Table GROUP BY Col1
```

Comment: The request may be a little confusing talking of dropped duplicates. It is actually not about deleting rows, but about omitting rows from a query. Anyway, your statement is syntactically wrong. After `NOT` there must be a boolean expression, but you have a table there (a list of col1s with their max dates). You want `WHERE (col1, MAX(date) NOT IN (SELECT col1, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY col1)`. Not all DBMS support tuples in `[NOT] IN`, though.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to remove the part in front of the brackets. Only the part inside is needed.